# Error on "C" ternary operator to return a value

Tags: c, type-conversion, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have done this code, to search a value using Exponential search algorithm

```
int exponential_search(int *array, size_t size, int value)
{
    size_t m = 1;
    size_t limit = 0;
    int out = 0;

    if (!array)
        return (-1);

    while (m < size && array[m] <= value)
    {
        printf("Value checked array[%ld] = [%d]", m, array[m]);
        m *= 2;
    }

    limit = (m < size) ? (m / 2) + 1 : size - (m / 2);
    out = binary_search(&array[m / 2], limit, value);

    return (out != -1) ? out + (m / 2) : -1;
}
```

When i compiled it using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`, i got this error message:

```
error: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression [-Werror=sign-compare]
  return (out != -1) ? out + (m / 2) : -1;
                                     ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

I can't understand why

When i change the "-1" for "1" it works, but i need return "-1", besides, I don't want to use if/else statement if is possible

Comment: `size_t m` is an unsigned type and `out + (m / 2)` gets promoted to that type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning/error you're seeing is because the second and third operands of the ternary operator have different type resulting in a conversion.

The second operand `out + (m / 2)` has type `size_t` because that is the type of `m` which carries out to the rest of the expression.  The third operand `-1` has type `int`.  Since the `?:` operator can only result in one type than the usual arithmetic conversions are applied to both to determine the type.

Because `size_t`, which is unsigned, is at least as large as `int`, the third operand is converted to `size_t`.  That means the value `-1` is converted to an unsigned value, the result of which will be a very large positive number (most likely 2<sup>64</sup> - 1).

The reason you don't get this error when the third operand is `1` is because converting the `int` value `1` to `size_t` won't change its value because it is in the range of a `size_t`, whereas `-1` is not.

You can prevent this conversion by casting `m` to `int`.  That will result in the second operand having type `int` so that the third operand is not converted.

```
return (out != -1) ? out + ((int)m / 2) : -1;
```

Comment: So clear, you know why ternary op, can only return just one type?

Comment: @Onyx All expressions have a single type that is determined at compile time.  In the case of the ternary operator, it is determined by looking at the two possible results and coming up with a common type.

Comment: The suggested fix will cause erroneous behaviour when `m > INT_MAX`. Perhaps it would be better to re-evaluate the choice of return type

Comment: It may be helpful to express clearly and directly the reason the compiler is providing a warning: The `? :` operator is required to figure a common type for the second and third operands and produce a value of that type. Because the second operand is unsigned and the third operand is signed, there is some concern that the programmer intended to produce a signed result, but the common type will be unsigned. Therefore, the compiler is warning the programmer that the result may not be what they intended. It is not an error the C standard requires, just something suspicious.